How to generate full-page QR code from command line?
I'd like to generate a full-page QR code from the command line.  The following command sort of accomplishes this:
qrencode -o- https://example.net | convert png:- -gravity center -units pixelsperinch -density 300 -resize 2551x3295 -extent 2551x3295 qrcode.pdf

Unfortunately, the resulting QR code is quite blurry, as though imagemagick is doing some sort of unwanted antialiasing.
Is there a way to make the code completely crisp, or just a better/simpler approach to generating a PDF file with a full-page QR code?

Why not ask qrencode to make the output bigger in the first place? qrencode -s 33 -d 300, for example

I could, but then I'd have to know roughly how large the QR code is going to be to fill a page.  Right now I'm just using pdflatex and \includeimage to make it full size, and it scales up without any blurriness whatsoever.  That's just a bit clunky, so it seems like I should be able to do something easier with imagemagick, but I can't figure it out.

So the default is 3 pixels to a dot (or whatever you call, an individual square in the code), and the final image was 99x99 which is how I came up with those magic numbers above. But anyway, if it works with pdflatex, yes, there should be some way with imagemagick.

Change your resize to scale which uses "nearest neighbour" interpolation - i.e. it only uses colours already present in the original image without introducing new ones by doing interpolation between the old ones:
qrencode -o- https://example.net | convert png:- -gravity center -units pixelsperinch -density 300 -scale 2551x3295 -extent 2551x3295 qrcode.pdf


